# Abort tree traversal with ParseTreeWalker

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My Task is to write a 'Calc'-Compiler for the [Triangle Abstract Machine](http://www.dcs.gla.ac.uk/~daw/books/PLPJ/), that translates a Calc source file to a TAM Assembly.

The Calc language consists of variable declarations (only integers supported),

```
var someID : integer;
```

assignments

```
someID = 1+5-8+someID;
```

and a print function.

```
print(someID-10)
```

Currently I am using ANTLR4s tree walking facilities by using listeners to translate Calc to the TAM Assembly (and its working).
Now I would like to abort the tree traversal, if a context error occurs (e.g. usage of an undefined variable).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could throw a [`CancellationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CancellationException.html). The [`BailErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BailErrorStrategy.html) in ANTLR 4 aborts parsing when a syntax error occurs by throwing a [`ParseCancellationException`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/misc/ParseCancellationException.html), which is derived from `CancellationException`.